# How to get the object details from SQS body?

Tags: python, amazon-sqs, boto3

I have the following script:

```
import boto3

# Get the service resource
sqs = boto3.resource('sqs')

# Get the queue
queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName='')

for message in queue.receive_messages():
    print(message.body)

    # Let the queue know that the message is processed
    message.delete()
```

It returns the following as the message's body:

```
{"Records":[{"eventVersion":"2.0","eventSource":"aws:s3","awsRegion":"us-west-2","eventTime":"2017-03-03T11:06:25.329Z","eventName":"ObjectCreated:Copy","userIdentity":{"principalId":"AWS:<id>:<lambda_name>"},"requestParameters":{"sourceIPAddress":"54.186.104.49"},"responseElements":{"x-amz-request-id":"8577BEEB91F199BF","x-amz-id-2":"<>="},"s3":{"s3SchemaVersion":"1.0","configurationId":"PutFromSisterBucket","bucket":{"name":"<bucket_name>","ownerIdentity":{"principalId":"<>"},"arn":"arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_nmae>"},"object":{"key":"<object_key>","size":1990,"versionId":"anHi0ukirRiApp4jyoSTz2oVGOejR6tJ","sequencer":"0058B94E3141A83718"}}}]}
```

How do I get the value of the "key" inside the "object"?

Currently, the entire result is a string. Is there any way I can do without string indexing or regex match?

Comment: You can use [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)?

Comment: See here for an example to get the attributes you want - https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/sqs.html#processing-messages

Comment: `json.loads` works.  Thank you.  Pl add an answer :)

Comment: `json.loads` may work, but I think the library has more to offer, and you should probably try using that first, the example seems on the lines with what you intend on doing.

Comment: @shad0w_wa1k3r I'm trying to do the exact same thing as but am having no luck with the link you provided. I would prefer to use boto and not json.loads. Have you had any luck with this ?

Comment: Unsure what you're having issues with, but you can refer to the detailed [documentation for receive_messages](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Queue.receive_messages) @fpolig01 If you're still stuck, you may want to ask a new question (& have this as a reference somewhere)

Comment: @shad0w_wa1k3r I did some more research and it looks like the data I'm trying to access is within the message.body. The example in the documentation demonstrates accessing a "message attribute", which needs to be defined/setup when the message is created. I don't think my message has any attributes. I'm not sure if there is a way to access keys/values within the message.body

Comment: @fpolig01 Well, if your results are consistent, I don't see why you can't use `json.loads`, it's a built-in library after all.

Comment: @shad0w_wa1k3r Yup, that's what I ended up doing. It's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable `message` is string you need to load it with `json.loads`, to parse to dict type in python, so you can use it like a json:

```
import json

for message in queue.receive_messages():
    message_dict = json.loads(message)
    record = message_dict["Records"][0]
    content = record["s3"]["object"]["key"]
    print(content)
```